# Need a help to debug PHP code

Tags: php

I have following code as below,

```
 <?php
    $a = [1,2,3];
    foreach($a as &$val) {
        $val = $val + 1;
    }

    foreach($a as $val) {
        $val = $val - 1;
    }

    var_dump($a);

    // output 2,3,1
?>
```

I got output 2,3,1 as final array instead of 2,3,4 and i can't understand how php is interpreting this code, Can anyone help me to understand how the things is going here?

Comment: @AlonEitan No, the first pass-by-reference should create `2,3,4` and be unaffected by the seconded `foreach`.

Comment: @BenM Oh, missed that. Thanks for letting me know

Comment: Accessing the loop variable of `foreach` by reference means searching for trouble. Don't do it!

Comment: The answer to your question is explained in the [documentation of `foreach`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) in a big red warning box.

Answer (score 5):

You need to call `unset()` on the reference in your first `foreach()` to get the expected behaviour:

```
$a = [1, 2, 3];

foreach($a as &$val) 
{
    $val = $val + 1;
}

unset($val);

// $a = [2, 3, 4];
```

See the note in the [documentation](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) for this:

> Reference of a `$value` and the last array element remain even after the
>   foreach loop. It is recommended to destroy it by `unset()`.

Comment: I think question is about why output is [2,3,1] instead of [2,3,4]

Comment: *without an `unset($value)`, `$value` is still a reference to the last item: $arr[3]*. It's in the docs, guys.

Comment: `unset()` should be called **after** foreach, not inside of it.

Comment: @rob006 It's actually irrelevant in this instance: https://eval.in/1006699

Comment: @BenM result may be the same, but it does not make any sense to put it inside of foreach, it only adds unnecessary overhead.

Comment: @rob006 Fair point, updated the answer (although I *think* the garbage collector is still intelligent enough for this to not cause unnecessary overheads).